# In log4j, why is "OFF" the highest logging level?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have been struggling to intuitively understand the Log4J Levels.

[It says that](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29578_01/webhelp/cas_webcrawler/src/cwcg_config_log4j_file.html) :

```
OFF has the highest possible rank and is intended to turn off logging.
```

How does it make sense to say OFF the highest rank?  I would rather think that `DEBUG` or `ALL` is the highest , i.e the level which produces the *most* data.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samudra Gupta  says in his book *Pro Apache Log4j*, Second Edition <sup>**1**</sup> (the emphasis is mine):

> The levels have unique integer values attached to them and are arranged in the preceding list from ***lowest*** to ***highest*** value.

Internally an integer value is assigned to each level:

```
Level   Int Value
-----   ----------------- 
ALL     Integer.MIN_VALUE
TRACE   5000
DEBUG   10000
INFO    20000
WARN    30000
ERROR   40000
FATAL   50000
OFF     Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Consider the following method:

```java
public void info(Object message, Throwable t) {
    if (repository.isDisabled(Level.INFO_INT))
        return;
    if (Level.INFO.isGreaterOrEqual(this.getEffectiveLevel()))
        forcedLog(FQCN, Level.INFO, message, t);
}
```

The first `if` verifies the threshold. It will be written to the log if the level is greater than or equal to the threshold. e.g. if the threshold is `INFO`, then `ERROR > INFO` but `TRACE < INFO`. So `TRACE` will not be written.

The second `if` verifies the level of logger. e.g. if the level of logger is `OFF`, `ERROR < OFF`, so `ERROR` will not be written.

Accordingly, a level with high value will not allow to levels with smaller values write in the log. And `OFF` has the highest possible rank (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Another way to see this is, as [*Wikipedia* says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log4j_1_Log_level), is the level of severity. And `OFF` has the highest level of severity.

---

*Notes*

1. Samudra Gupta, "Understanding Apache log4j" in *Pro Apache Log4j*, Second Edition (Berkeley, California: Apress, 2005), 24.